# Onmouseover running multiple times while hovering on element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does onmouseover run multiple times while I hover over one element?

I'm trying to run a simple animation when the user hovers over an icon but it runs multiple times.

I'm testing it here:

http://lujanventas.com/test.php

Anyway, any ideas on how to fix it? maybe using a listener instead?

This is the javascript running onmouseover:

```
function upIcon(n) {
    console.log("Mouseover icon: " + n);
    $('#icon' + n).animate({ backgroundPositionY : "-=15px" }, 200 );
    $('#icon' + n).animate({ backgroundPositionY : "+=15px" }, 200 );
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you are calling animate() twice in your code on the same element, using opposite directions? I don't see any visible effect on your test page.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`. The former fires only when the cursor enters the region of the element and the latter fires when the cursor moves between descendants as well.

I added this code to your page via my console and it worked as expected:

```
//bind an event handler to each nav element for the mouseenter event
$('.categoryButtons').children().bind('mouseenter', function () {

    //call the `upIcon` function with the index of the current element
    upIcon(($(this).index() + 1));
});
```

I also removed the inline `onmouseover` code for each nav item.

### Update

You can use your existing function a bit differently and not use the anonymous function for your event handler (notice the function chaining to avoid duplicate selections):

```
function upIcon(event) {
    var n = ($(this).index() + 1);
    $('#icon' + n).animate({ backgroundPositionY : "-=15px" }, 200 ).animate({ backgroundPositionY : "+=15px" }, 200 );
}

$('.categoryButtons').children().bind('mouseenter', upIcon);
```

When you reference an existing function as the event handler, it gets passed the `event` object like any other event handler and you can also use `this` to refer to the element on which the event was triggered.

Comment: Thanks, it works. However I'm struggling to make it work with all icons. Could you change it so it works with the rest of them? I might to get it right anyway but it's a bit above me

Comment: I removed .first() but I don't know how to get which element I'm hovering. If I can get it I can just replace it inside upIcon() and that would be it

Comment: @Liso22 `($(this).index() + 1)` gets the index of the icon being hovered-over and adds one since `.index()` will start at zero and we want to start at one. `.index()` gets the index of the element based on its sibling elements which happen to be the other buttons. I've also posted an **update** that explains how to better use your existing function as an event handler.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things:

- To solve your problem I would use the mouseenter event instead - this means when the mouse enters the element the code is executed, and then you can use mouseleave to change the animation again when the mouse pointer leaves.
- Rather than using messy onmouseover events, you would be better using jQuery for what it is meant for - unobtrusive codes. Bind events to the elements e.g.

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".icon").mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).animate({ backgroundPositionY : "-=15px" }, 200 );
       });

       $(".icon").mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).animate({ backgroundPositionY : "+=15px" }, 200 );
       });


  });
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery, you could use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`--it's designed to protect you from mouseout events when there are multiple items within your target.

More: http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

So, you'd want to remove the events attached to each item (which isn't great form in the first place, and instead do the following in a script block:

```
$('.categoryButtons').find('a').mouseenter(function(){
    /* ... Do something, probably depending on $(this).attr('id') or $(this).attr('rel') ... */
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using onmouseover, I'd recommend using JQuery's mouseenter to avoid the multiple firing of the handler due to event bubbling:

http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/